# Automatic tool for resolving left-recursion within CFG

Tags: scientific-computing, nlp

Though facing the fear that someone might not like my question but does somebody know a useful tool to either

- resolve left recursion or to
- simplify

a context-free grammar automatically ?

I need to resolve a rather long chain of left-recursion in my grammar.

So far I've tried [this](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/images/PLT/PLTelralgorithm.gif) algorithm and [this](http://lab.brainonfire.net/CFG/remove-left-recursion.html) tool. But both are only applicable for smaller grammars and provide practically unusable results (1000's of rules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During my research I found two excellent tools for dealing with CFG's I want to share here (since I am sure they will help others as they helped me):

- http://lab.brainonfire.net/CFG/remove-left-recursion.html

> This application removes left-corner cycles from a context-free
>   grammar to make it more acceptable for LL parsers. Of course, this can
>   change the associativity of operators in the language, and this does
>   not resolve problems with first sets, follow sets, and nullable
>   symbols.

- http://cfge.tw-db.info/

> Allows the user to specify a context-free grammar (either using a GUI
>   or text-only). Demonstrates standard context-free grammar
>   normalization algorithms:
>
> - reduced form
> - Chomsky normal form
> - strict Chomsky normal form
> - epsilon-free form
> - chain-rule-free form
> - Greibach normal form
>
> In addition, the CYK algorithm can be used on sCNF grammars to parse a
>   word and generate a parse tree in case the world is generated by the
>   grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another [automated tool](https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/left_rec).

- Easy input format
- Better output format
- Also supports multi-letter symbols

Comment: What happens if the link you provided changes?  How would your answer still be valid?  You should use the link only as a reference and include as much information as possible.